# How configure intellij java formatter to format .stream() like other methods

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm trying to set up the IntelliJ formatter to use the same new line format for streams as for other method calls.

If I got a line of code which exceeds the limit of 100 characters, IntelliJ formats it like this:

```java
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
stringBuilder
    .append("foo")
    .append("foo")
    .append("foo")
    .append("foo")
    .append("foo")
    .append("foo")
    .append("foo")
    .append("foo");
```

If I got a line of code containing a stream which exceeds the limit of 100 characters too, intellij starts a new line after the stream statement:

```java
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.subList(0, 2).stream()
    .filter(foo -> foo.equals(foo))
    .filter(foo -> foo.equals(foo))
    .filter(foo -> foo.equals(foo));
```

How can I tell the formatter to have the same formatting for streams like other methods?

```java
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
list
    .subList(0, 2)
    .stream()
    .filter(foo -> foo.equals(foo))
    .filter(foo -> foo.equals(foo))
    .filter(foo -> foo.equals(foo));
```

This formatting should only apply if the code line exceeds the limit of 100 characters, otherwise it should stay in one line.

Edit: I updated my intellij version to 2019.2 and reimported my CodeStyle xml.
Now i can not reproduce my problem anymore.

Comment: Have you already tried using the "Wrap first call" option? You can find it in Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> Java -> Wrapping and Braces -> Chained Method Calls .

Comment: @ErikNellessen Yes, I've already tried it - still the same result :/

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce the problem with IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2019.2. I created the following class:

```
public class Foo {

    void bar() {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        stringBuilder.append("foo").append("foo").append("foo").append("foo").append("foo").append("foo").append("foo").append("foo");

        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.subList(0, 2).stream().filter(foo -> foo.equals(foo)).filter(foo -> foo.equals(foo)).filter(foo -> foo.equals(foo));
    }

}
```

After reformatting (CTRL+ALT+L), the code looked like this:

```
public class Foo {

    void bar() {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        stringBuilder
                .append("foo")
                .append("foo")
                .append("foo")
                .append("foo")
                .append("foo")
                .append("foo")
                .append("foo")
                .append("foo");

        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list
                .subList(0, 2)
                .stream()
                .filter(foo -> foo.equals(foo))
                .filter(foo -> foo.equals(foo))
                .filter(foo -> foo.equals(foo));
    }

}
```

Here are my code style settings as an XML:

```
<code_scheme name="Project" version="173">
  <codeStyleSettings language="JAVA">
    <option name="ALIGN_MULTILINE_CHAINED_METHODS" value="true" />
    <option name="ALIGN_MULTILINE_PARAMETERS_IN_CALLS" value="true" />
    <option name="METHOD_PARAMETERS_WRAP" value="2" />
    <option name="THROWS_LIST_WRAP" value="1" />
    <option name="METHOD_CALL_CHAIN_WRAP" value="2" />
    <option name="WRAP_FIRST_METHOD_IN_CALL_CHAIN" value="true" />
    <option name="BINARY_OPERATION_WRAP" value="1" />
    <option name="ARRAY_INITIALIZER_WRAP" value="1" />
  </codeStyleSettings>
</code_scheme>
```

Comment: You should be able to reproduce it, if you set the "Chained method calls" to "Wrap if long" (instead of "Wrap always"). Keep in mind to copy paste my example again, as you got the "Keep when reformatting" -> "Line breaks" option active.

I edited my question to underline that the multi line format should only appear when a code line exceeds the limit.

Comment: now that I've updated to Idea 2019.2 (i used 2018.1.8 before) and reimported my code style file (which is the one from [google](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/google/styleguide/gh-pages/intellij-java-google-style.xml)), i can not reproduce it myself.

Comment: If I set the "Chained method calls" to "Wrap if long" (instead of "Wrap always"), IntelliJ IDEA formats the code much differently. It will not put every chained method call into a new line, but leave lots of them in the same line until the 100 character limit is reached.

Comment: same goes for me. as i can not reproduce the original one, should i close/delete this question? (sorry, its my first stackoverflow question)

Comment: I am not an expert on stackoverflow either. I would say that you should edit your question and add a line saying that you could not reproduce the problem any more. And you should add a line that describes how you came to the point where the code was formatted as you wished. That way, your question can still help other people who have similar problems.